# Why object non-optional ignore its weak property? [Swift]

Tags: memory-management

I have 2 classes **Car** and **Owner**, they have weak preference to each other. After I assign nil to one object. That object is still not deallocated. Like code bellow, as far as I understand object **vinfast (Car)** must be deallocated because its reference count equal zero.

Especially is if I change **james (Owner)** to optional, it works. **james** is non-optional, it doesn't work.

Can someone help me explain why **vinfast (Car)** is deallocated if and only if **james (Owner)** is optional?

```
import Foundation

class Car {
    var model: String
    weak var owner: Owner?

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        print("Car is being allocated")
    }

    deinit {
        //is not called
        print("Car have been deallocated")
    }
}

class Owner {
    weak var car: Car?
}

var vinfast: Car? = Car(model: "Go1")
let james: Owner = Owner()
james.car = vinfast
vinfast = nil
```

Output:

> Car is being allocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that it belongs to Playground issues (Swift 4.2), after I create small project and put it inside. The code run as well, that object is deallocated.